# C++ clear/overwrite content from beginning of file

Tags: c++, fstream, ifstream

I need to erase or overwrite(erase would be better) a number of bytes from the start of a file. The content are first read into a data structure the after deleting new content are written.

Currently I have the reading and writing part. How can I do the data clearing part? Ask if you want to know anything else. Thanks, sorry for bad English :)

```
typedef struct header {
   char    version[5]; //Offset 0, length 5, Archiver version
   int     files_no;   //Offset 5, length 8, Number of files in the archive
   char    desc[256];  //Offset 13, length 256, Archive description, Header size 296??

   header() {
       strcpy(version, "0.20");
       strcpy(desc, "THIS IS A DESCRIPTION FIELD WITH 256BYTE!");
   }
}archiveHeader;

int archive(char *argv[], int argc) {
   archiveHeader   archive_struct_write, archive_struct_read;
   string          output = argv[argc-1]; output += ".n0b"; //Name of file to modify
   int             write_counter = 1;

   ofstream file_write(output.c_str(), ios::binary | ios::app);
   file_write.seekp(0, file_write.beg);

   ifstream file_read(output.c_str(), ios::binary);
   file_read.read((char*)&archive_struct_read, sizeof(archive_struct_read)); //Read existing beginning data

   //Steps for erasing the read stuff goes here.    

   write_counter = archive_struct_read.files_no;
   archive_struct_write.files_no = write_counter + 1;

   file_write.write((char*)&archive_struct_write, sizeof(archive_struct_write)); //New beginning data written
   file_read.close();
   file_write.close();

   write_counter++;

   return 0;
}
```

Edit : Buffering everything after the beginning bytes and writing to a new file is not an option, the file can vary in size upto GBs. Thanks!

Comment: Please, don't use `typedef struct`. Just use `struct`. You are writing in `C++`, not in `C`.

Comment: @Fureeish Noted, thanks!

Comment: You can override data in file, you can truncate end of it. Erasing data from begining or in middle without overwriting whole file could be only possible if specific OS/filesystem provides such special ability. Normally you cannot do that.

Comment: This is easy enough using the original C routines, fopen, fseek, fwrite and fclose.  Random access.

Comment: you're probably stuck with writing a new file (you don't have to buffer the entire original file in memory though - you can do so in blocks of whatever buffer size works for you). Alternatively, you could rewrite the same file by shifting data over to the start of the file, but that's not as easy.